# Wave equation and Energy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

Consider the following conditions:

- $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\space \space \space x\in (0,L), t>0$
- $u(0,x)=u_0(x) \quad\quad\quad\quad x\in [0,L]$
- $u_t(0,x)=u_1(x) \quad\quad\quad\space \space \space x\in [0,L]$
- $u(t,0)=u(t,L)=0 \quad\space\space \space \space t\in [0,T]$

The Energy Function: $E(t)=\int_{0} ^{L} c^2(u_x)^2 dx \space + \space \int_{0} ^{L} (u_t)^2 dx $

Show the energy conservation: For each twice continuously partially differentiable solution $u$: $[0,T] \times [0,L] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ of the conditions above for the wave equation the following relation applies: $E(t)=E(0), \space$ for $\space t\geq 0$

After that show that there is at most one twice continuously partially differentiable solution for the above given conditions.

My attempt:

$E'(t)=\int_{0} ^{L} 2 u_t u_{tt}+ 2 c^2 u_x u_{xt} dx $

Integrating the second part gives:

$2c^2 \int_{0} ^{L} u_x u_{xt} dx = 2 c^2 (u_x u_t-\int_{0} ^{L} u_t u_{xx} dx)$

$u_x u_t $ vanishes because of $u_t (t,0)=u_t (t,L)=0$

Now $E'(t)=\int_{0} ^{L} 2 u_t u_{tt}-2 c^2 u_t u_{xx} dx\quad $ with $\quad u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}=0 $

$E'(t)=0$, I get to this point and now I don't have an idea of how to proceed

Comment: If a function has zero derivative, what can you conclude about it?

Comment: $E(t)=const. $, the problem I have is how to find the unique solution, and how to prove that $E(0)=E(t) $

Comment: You’ve shown conservation by showing the derivative is zero. To prove uniqueness, suppose you have two solutions. Look at the difference of the two functions. What PDE does it solve? What initial/boundary conditions? Therefore (some reasoning involving energy)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E'(t) =0\implies E(t) =C$$ for some constant $C$. In particular $E(0) =C$ so $E(t) =E(0) $ for every value of $t$. To prove uniqueness suppose you have two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, and consider $u=u_1-u_2$. The function $u$ solves the homogeneus equation with boundary conditions all equal to zero, which implies that the energy is zero. It implies that $$0=E(t)=\int_0^L \left(c^2(u_x)^2+(u_t)^2\right)dx\implies c^2(u_x)^2+(u_t)^2=0\implies c^2(u_x)^2=0=(u_t)^2\implies u(t,x)=0.$$ The reasoning is as follow: we have an integral of a positive function over a positive domain, which implies that the integrand is zero, but the sum of two real squares is zero if and only if both are zero. It implies that $u(x,t)$ is constant and takes the same value as its boundary, which is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: You're welcome :)